# Rails 3.0.0.rc profiling: Thousands of Regexp#===(d1) calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, ruby-on-rails-3

I was getting 0.5 reqs/s on the front page of my rails app (a very simple, mostly static page that made a couple of database calls, but nothing that WEBrick said took longer than 0.8 ms), served with thin. I added ruby-prof profiling tools to my ApplicationController via the instructions at Dan Mange's blog and dumped the call graph to standard out.

Here's a little bit of the graph: http://pastie.org/1063281

It seems absurd, but googling for "Regexp#===" finds nothing interesting.

Anyone seen anything like this? Better yet, know how to fix it?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'thin'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'pg'
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'ruby-prof'
gem 'daemons'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying some of the other ruby-prof outputs.  If you grab it from github there have been a few added recently (but not yet released).

http://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof